# Debugging issue Android application in Visual studio Xamarin

Tags: android, visual-studio-2010, xamarin

I have downloaded all requirements and my project ran perfectly. Until i was viewing project properties i accidently added androidmanifest.xml file and then when i run the application it is giving runtime error 
[image]

No more detail of error is shown. Can anyone tell me atleast where can i find error detail and  how to fix it. I have even deleted my project and added a new one but nothing changed.

some other details are

```
09-17 14:34:47.954 D/dalvikvm(15610): Late-enabling CheckJNI
09-17 14:34:47.955 D/dalvikvm(15610): threadid=2: interp stack at 0x49254000
09-17 14:34:47.956 D/dalvikvm(15610): threadid=3: interp stack at 0x4925c000
09-17 14:34:47.957 D/jdwp    (15610): prepping for JDWP over ADB
09-17 14:34:47.957 D/jdwp    (15610): ADB transport startup
09-17 14:34:47.958 D/dalvikvm(15610): threadid=4: interp stack at 0x49264000
09-17 14:34:47.959 D/jdwp    (15610): JDWP: thread running
09-17 14:34:47.959 D/jdwp    (15610): acceptConnection
09-17 14:34:47.960 D/jdwp    (15610): trying to receive file descriptor from ADB
09-17 14:34:47.960 D/dalvikvm(15610): threadid=5: interp stack at 0x4926c000
09-17 14:34:47.964 D/dalvikvm(15610): threadid=6: interp stack at 0x49274000
09-17 14:34:47.965 D/dalvikvm(15610): threadid=6: calling run()
09-17 14:34:47.965 D/dalvikvm(15610): threadid=7: interp stack at 0x4927c000
09-17 14:34:47.966 D/dalvikvm(15610): threadid=7: calling run()
09-17 14:34:47.966 D/dalvikvm(15610): threadid=8: interp stack at 0x4bd36000
09-17 14:34:47.976 D/dalvikvm(15610): threadid=8: calling run()
09-17 14:34:47.987 I/dalvikvm(15610): Turning on JNI app bug workarounds for target SDK version 8...
09-17 14:34:48.006 D/dalvikvm(15610): threadid=9: interp stack at 0x4bd3e000
09-17 14:34:48.022 D/dalvikvm(15610): threadid=10: interp stack at 0x4bd46000
09-17 14:34:48.066 I/ActivityThread(15610): Pub ProteinTracker.ProteinTracker.mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.__mono_init__: mono.MonoRuntimeProvider
09-17 14:34:48.069 D/dalvikvm(15610): Trying to load lib /data/data/ProteinTracker.ProteinTracker/lib/libmonodroid.so 0x416a0b58
09-17 14:34:48.070 D/dalvikvm(15610): Added shared lib /data/data/ProteinTracker.ProteinTracker/lib/libmonodroid.so 0x416a0b58
09-17 14:34:48.074 W/MonoDroid-Debugger(15610): Trying to initialize the debugger with options: --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,loglevel=0,address=127.0.0.1:8919,server=y,embedding=1
09-17 14:34:48.167 W/MonoDroid-Debugger(15610): Accepted stdout connection: 51
09-17 14:34:48.928 E/mono    (15610): WARNING: The runtime version supported by this application is unavailable.
09-17 14:34:48.928 E/mono    (15610): Using default runtime: v2.0.50727
09-17 14:34:48.981 D/dalvikvm(15610): threadid=11: interp stack at 0x4bf00000
09-17 14:34:48.981 D/dalvikvm(15610): threadid=12: interp stack at 0x4c783000
09-17 14:34:49.889 F/        (15610): Invalid bridge callback version. Expected 3 but got 2
09-17 14:34:49.889 I/mono    (15610): Stacktrace:
09-17 14:34:49.889 I/mono    (15610): 
The program 'Mono' has exited with code 255 (0xff).
```

Answer (score 1):

I didnt find any answer to this bug but i just made it working by changing debug mode to release but still its not working in debug mode. Just a temporary solution. If someone has any other suggestions its appreciated.